# How to get string from CP866 bytes

Tags: c++, encoding, character-encoding

My program read bytes from file and try convert it to string. Head of file is a text in CP866.

```
    iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-8","CP866");
    char* iconv_in = bytes.data(); //Bytes is a char vector
    char* iconv_out = (char *)malloc(counter * sizeof(char)); //counter is a length of bytes array (char vector)
    size_t iconv_in_bytes =counter;
    size_t iconv_out_bytes = counter;

    size_t ret = iconv(cd, &iconv_in, &iconv_in_bytes, &iconv_out, &iconv_out_bytes);

    if ((size_t) -1 == ret) {
            cout << "Error convert";
            return NULL;
    }
```

Program ends with failure (Error convert). And this way is not simple and beautiful. There is exist more simple solution?

Comment: When `iconv` return `-1` you need to check `errno` to see what went wrong. Most likely there's not enough room in the output buffer, and `errno` will be equal to `E2BIG`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't use `malloc` in C++ code, use `new[]`.. Or better yet, use `std::string` (or alternatively `std::vector`).